# In Drupal 6 What is the hook I would use to override user_pas_submit?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I need some additional functionality added to user_pass_submit. This must be added without changing the core. What is the hook I would use to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` to replace the submit handler for the `user_pass` form with your own module's copy of `user_pass_submit`, altered as necessary.

Something like this...

```
function MODULE_form_user_pass_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#submit'] = array('MODULE_user_pass_submit');
}

function MODULE_user_pass_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  global $language;

  $account = $form_state['values']['account'];
  // Mail one time login URL and instructions using current language.
  _user_mail_notify('password_reset', $account, $language);
  watchdog('user', 'Password reset instructions mailed to %name at %email.', array('%name' => $account->name, '%email' => $account->mail));
  drupal_set_message(t('Further instructions have been sent to your e-mail address.'));

  $form_state['redirect'] = 'user';
  return;
}
```

Of course, this falls down if you have multiple modules trying to do

Comment: Thanks! I was circling around this answer but my newbie status prevented comprehension. Much appreciated.